# Twilio URL not routing correctly in Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a twilio app that is making phone calls.  I put the guts of it in a Worker, and now cannot get the API to recognize the url I am passing as a valid url for my TwiML response.  Code is below.  Any ideas?  Also note that I have tried both `#{root_path}connect` and `#{root_url}connect`

Worker

```
@numbers.each do |dial|
    if (dial.phone_number =~ /[\(\)0-9\- \+\.]{10,11}/).nil?
      raise Exception, "bad phone number"
    end
    call = client.account.calls.create(
    :from => my_number,
    :to => dial.phone_number,
    :url => "#{root_path}connect"
      )
```

controller

```
def connect
  response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say 'The Time Has come to take over the world Pinky', :voice => 'alice'
  end
  render text: response.text
end
```

routes

`root :to => 'call_logs#index'`

`resources :call_logs, only: [:create, :index] do
    collection { post :call_score_range,:call_warrants_with_date_range,:connect }
  end`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think your problem is that the worker has no concept of Rails' routes. Routes are only available by default in controllers and views, so you are probably not passing a URL to Twilio.

I can't see where you call your worker from in the first place, but one idea would be to pass the URL you want to send to the API into the worker from where it is created in a controller.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if there's anything else I can do for you.